# Insert Row without shifting formulas down

Tags: excel

I want to insert row for each day to add new values, and I have a `SUM` formula to add up all the values from each day.

How do I stop excel from automatically shifting my `SUM` formula's range down when I insert a row?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put a dollar sign in front of what you don't want to change. If the range is `A1:B2`, make it `$A$1:$B$2`. Add and remove each dollar sign as needed.

EDIT: use `SUM(INDIRECT("$H$4:$H$50000"))`

Comment: I tryed that, excel still shifts the values down by one, when I insert row.

Comment: Either you did it wrong, or I'm misunderstanding your question. Help us help you by rephrasing your question.

Comment: Before inserting a row : SUM($H$4:$H$50000)

Comment: After inserting a row : SUM($H$5:$H$50001)

Comment: use `SUM(INDIRECT("$H$4:$H$50000"))`

Comment: INDIRECT is a volatile function and should be avoided when possible,  not much help but just FYI you runtime will slow. See more on volatile function: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: Is there any way to use INDIRECT() and still be able to see Excel's visual color box around the referenced cells?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a named range with the formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$H:$H,4):INDEX(Sheet1!$H:$H,50000)
```

To create it do `Ctrl-F3` and fill in the name and definition.  In Excel 2010 it would look like this:

[image]

Then your formula is just `=SUM(StaticRange)`

Comment: Best Answer, non volatile function.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but I just ran into this today. In my case, I was able to avoid the issue by using `OFFSET()` to define the range for the `SUM()` instead of entering the range directly.

So, instead of `=SUM(A2:A50)` you can use `=SUM(OFFSET(A1, 1, 0, 50))`. How does this help? If the cell that you reference in the `OFFSET()` function is outside the range for the formula, Excel typically won't modify it when you insert/delete rows.

Your mileage may vary since the inner workings of Excel are a bit mysterious to me, but this technique worked well for me once I understood what the `OFFSET()` function was doing.

Reference: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/offset.htm

Comment: Like the `INDIRECT` method, this Volitile.   Also, it's vulnerable to inserting a row at row 1,  so isn't quite as good.  That said,  I'd say valid these issues and use the `INDEX` method

Comment: Actually, `INDIRECT` requires you to hard code ranges in a string which breaks a lot of functionality. For some use cases `INDEX` works great, but if you have a dynamic spreadsheet where you add and remove columns regularly, you give yourself a lot of extra maintenance managing static ranges. :)